# Finding and removing entries not in sequence in Python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, series

I have a series with n elements. For each n, n must be <= n + 1.
How can I remove entries that violate this rule?
Example code:

```
nums = pd.Series([1,1,2,2,3,4,2,2,2,5,5,5,6,7,8,5,5,9])
#some code here#
print(nums)
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     4
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     5
10    5
11    5
12    6
13    7
14    8
15    5
16    5
17    9
```

While `nums` are in sequence, some of the entries can be duplicated (see index 2-3 and 6-8).
I'm thinking using a for loop for iterate

```
for i in nums:
  #check i <= i + 1#
```

And use the resulting boolean series to subset `nums`, but I couldn't figure out the rest of the loop or namely how to access `i+1` index's value

Comment: i think you need a simple boolean like `nums[nums <= nums.index]` ? if that's not correct please post your expceted output

Comment: _n must be <= n + 1_ This rule makes no sense.  _Every_ number is less than or equal to itself plus one.

Comment: I'm guessing the question is nth <= (n+1th element)

Comment: Also, the output of `print(nums)` does not seem to match its initialization.  e.g. the last four numbers in the initialization are `8,5,5,9`, but the last four numbers in the printed output are `6,7,8,9`.

Comment: Do you just want to sort it? Even though I'm not fluent in pandas, it should be able to sort a series by using `nums.sort()` or the like. Unless the task is to write your own sorting algorithm, then check the available literature, there is plenty everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for shift. It is a more pandas/pythonic way of going about this than a iteration using a loop.

```
  import pandas as pd
  nums = pd.Series([1,1,2,2,3,4,2,2,2,5,5,5,6,7,8,5,5,9])
  size = -1 #arbitrary
  while(nums.size != size): #go until don't need to remove more elements
    size = nums.size
    nums = nums[nums <= nums.shift(-1)].append(nums.tail(1))
  print(nums.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove each element that is `nums[i] <= nums[i+1]`, you can build a loop as you correctly said. You can also index `i+1` without an issue if you e.g. avoid indexing the final element with a `break`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nums = pd.Series([1,1,2,2,3,4,2,2,2,5,5,5,6,7,8,5,5,9])
#some code here#
print(nums)

for i,n in enumerate(nums):
  if i == len(nums)-1: break # avoid final index
  if nums[i] <= nums[i+1]: #check
    nums[i] = np.nan # mark removed elements with NaN

print(nums.dropna().astype('int64')) # remove NaNs
```

This will save the original indices and indicate where elements where removed. If you want a new series and are not interested in the original indices, you can also save the elements in a new list. The final result of the above solution using `NaN`s is:

```
5     4
14    8
17    9
dtype: int64
```